# Theming gtk2 pcmanfm or any gtk2 app

Tags: themes, gtk, gtkrc, gtkinspector

I'm using **PCManFM** and I want to **change the sidebar** to a grey color. I know there's a Gtk 3 version but I don't want to add another repository.
I'm also learning the Gtk+ UI toolkit and how Gtk theming works so I'd like to learn with this example.

Theming any Gtk3 app has become very easy with **Gtk inspector**, but that only works for Gtk3 apps and above. I couldn't make **gtk parasite** work For the Gtk2 version all I can apparently do is hopefully finding some theme that changed the sidebar. This is **probably** good to ask in **another question**, but having an inspector that works for any Gtk2 app about also help as well.

Here's a comparison where you can see [thunar and PCManFM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTXGO.png) side by side for reference.

Also this is all I was able to find, but nothing worked

https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=39441

https://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?t=36177

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566335

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, and `pcmanfm` is no longer a *supported* package though still provided from upstream Debian via 'universe' with *community* support.  Why ask here? as you don't mention anything on-topic (*no OS/release details were provided*)

Comment: Well, as you mention, it's a package provided in the Debian 'universe' I'm on sparkylinux which is a smaller distro but still based on Debian and using the same repositories as ubuntu.

I've read many other questions about gtk 2, gtkrc or the gtk inspector and NO ONE mentions their system details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so looking at other themes and tweaking everything turns out the latest PCManFM using the Gtk 2.0 uses the treeview (or maybe some themes don't have this ui set to a transparent color so the base[NORMAL] style doesn't work:

```
style "pcmanfm-sidebar"{
 GtkTreeView::even-row-color = "#ebeced"
}

widget "FmMainWin.*.FmPlacesView" style "pcmanfm-sidebar"
```